Finding a comparison function for a particular ODE when applying the Sturm–Picone comparison theorem
Given that $\phi(x)$ is a non-trivial solution of the ODE:  $y'' + \frac{1}{1+x^2}y = 0$ for $x > 0$, show that $\phi$ has infinitely many positive $0$s.
For this question, I've been given the hint that I'll need to use the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem, but previously, similar problems I've encountered allowed me to use $\sin(x)$ as a comparison function as the function that precedes $y$ was greater than or equal to $1$ in the interval $(0,\infty)$.
I also know that its possible to use the function $\frac{1}{x^2}$ as a comparison function, but in this case, $\frac{1}{1+x^2}< \frac{1}{x^2}$ on the interval $(0,\infty)$. Does anyone have a hint on how I can find a suitable comparison function $f(x)$ (where if I understand the theorem correctly, $f(x) \leq \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ on the interval $(0,\infty)$) such that I can apply the theorem to solve the problem?

Since $\frac{1}{2x^2}\leq\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ in the interval $[1,\infty)$, and $\sqrt{x}\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln x\right)$ is a solution to the ODE $y''+\frac{1}{2x^2}y=0$ that has infinitely many zeros in that interval, it follows from the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem that a non-trivial solution to the ODE $y''+\frac{1}{1+x^2}y=0$ also has infinitely many zeros in the interval $[1,\infty)$.
